# Why is 行く used in the sentence "すぐに出て行け"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances

I don't understand the role of 行く in the following sentence:

> すぐに出て行け！

As I understand it, the sentence sounds like "get out now!". Why not just say "すぐに出ろ"?
Is 行く used to emphasize 出る ?

For reference, the sentence is part of military training in the Japanese dub of the animated film [*Mulan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulan_(1998_film)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it emphasizes「出る」.「出て行く」is a set phrase meaning "to go out and away." You can interpret it as the verb「出る」in the「Vていく」form.

A verb in the「Vていく」form has many meanings. In this context, when「いく」is appended to any motion verb, it gives the nuance of moving away from a speaker's viewpoint. So,「すぐに出て行け」literally means "get out (go away from me) now!"

You might ask why「出て行く」is used not「出ていく」? If the「いく」in「Vていく」involves a physical movement, sometimes kanji is used. In other words, kanji is used if「いく」means to go in a literal sense. It is just like how「Vて置く」is used instead of「Vておく」if「置く」is used in a more literal sense.

Answer (score 8):

出て行く is a compound word whose command form (命令形) is idiomatically used to tell someone to get out or get lost. Why not "出ろ"? Well, in similar contexts 出ろ would mean "get out", "leave", or "exit" without the rudeness and/or anger associated with 出て行け

For example, if I am having friends over for a house party and I all of a sudden smell gas, I would tell my friends to get out of the kitchen and maybe evacuate the house as well. 「出ろ」「出な」「出なさい」「出て」would work in that scenario. On the other hand if one of the friends gets drunk and is being a jerk to other people, I might tell them to 「出て行け！」.

It is interesting also to note that in English "Get out!" works in either scenario, but "Get out of my house/room/apartment/car/home!" only works in the second situation.

Answer (score 2):

> Is 行く used to emphasize 出る ?

I wouldn't say so. 出て行け is just a go-to phrase when you want to say "Leave!". Changing it to something like 出て（ください）sounds almost polite, and saving the emotion from original is 出ろ which is (Get out) would mean you want someone out, not away, just out, also sounds like start of a fight（表に出ろ) :)

I think it's just one of compound verbs, very common in japanese, better get used to them. Things like 取り出す、飛び込む、飛び出す after hearing these it feels dry and soulless to use short alternatives.